# Xamarin Forms - Stuck on splash when change date to past on Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I start the application for the first time. After killing it then changing the date on Android device to some past date, then starting the app again it gets frozen on splash screen. 
Checking Android Studio logcat returns nothing. 
When doing the steps from VS, the same does not happen.

Checked XF versions 2.4.0.7486, 2.5.1.444934
Checked Android devices Moto X Play (7.1.1),Nexus 5(6.0.1)

Stuck on this for few days now.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue some time ago. Looks like this is Xamarin Forms or Visual Studio bug. You can find out report [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/2194).

Unfortunately there is no working solution for this issue right now.